# Cannot blast against specific NCBI databases

Tags: database, blast, bash, phylogenetics, blastn

I am having issues with some prokaryote reference genome databases (exact names : ref_prok_rep_genomes.*), that I downloaded from the NCBI website : https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/. Files in this database go from `ref_prok_rep_genomes.00` to `ref_prok_rep_genomes.12`.

In Linux command line, I was able to launch successfully the bash command  `blastn -query (my_query) -db ref_prok_re_.genomes.* -out (my_output)` with indexes from `00` to `05`, but this does not work from indexes `06` to `12` (with the same query and output files). The exact same thing occurs with `blastdbcmd -info -db ref_prok_rep_genomes.*`.

Each time the error displayed is the same: 
`BLAST Database error: Input db vol does not match lmdb vol`.

All the `ref_prok_rep_genomes` files are in the same folder. I downloaded them using `wget` and extracted them using `tar -zxvf`. All `ref_prok_rep_genomes.*` databases (indexes `00` to `12`) have `nhr`, `nin`, `nnd`, `nni`, `nog` and `nsq` files. The folder also contains `ref_prok_rep_genomes` files (without numbers), with  `nal`, `ndb`, `nos`, `not`, `ntf` and `nto` extensions respectively, as well as `taxdb.btd` and `taxdb.bti` files.

Do you guys have an idea of what's going on?

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Did you checked the integrity of the downloaded files? `wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/ref_prok_rep_genomes.??.tar.gz.md5 && md5sum -c *md5`

Comment: I just did. With any of the md5 files, it gave me 
```ref_prok_rep_genomes.00.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.01.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.02.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.03.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.04.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.05.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.06.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.07.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.08.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.09.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.10.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.11.tar.gz: OK
ref_prok_rep_genomes.12.tar.gz: OK```

Comment: Actually I understood what happened. NCBI's new version 5 databases use virtual LMDB memory. They give issues with the previous versions of ncbi-blast+.

  
I managed to fix the problem by (1) updating ncbi-blast+ (currently it is the 2.10.0 version), (2) deleting my previous databases, (3) downloading them again using ```update_blastdb.pl --decompress <database_name>``` instead of ```wget```